# SQL query for getting latest coordinates from database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question as a newbie: I have small project for fleetTracker, I want to get the latest coordinates for each fleet in a day, so i have gps database like below:

```
gpsDateTime         | long | lat  | fleetNumber
--------------------+------+------+-------------
2018-10-03 14:11:00 | 123  | -123 | ABC1234
2018-10-03 14:21:00 | 124  | -124 | ABC1234
2018-10-03 14:31:00 | 125  | -125 | ABC1234
2018-10-03 14:41:00 | 126  | -126 | ABC1234
2018-10-03 14:51:00 | 127  | -127 | ABC1234
......
2018-10-04 14:11:00 | 123  | -123 | ABC1234
2018-10-04 14:21:00 | 124  | -124 | ABC1234
2018-10-04 14:31:00 | 125  | -125 | ABC1234
2018-10-04 14:41:00 | 126  | -126 | ABC1234
2018-10-04 14:51:00 | 127  | -127 | ABC1234
......    
2018-10-03 14:11:00 | 123  | -123 | JKL4321
......
2018-10-03 14:21:00 | 124  | -124 | JKL4322
2018-10-03 14:31:00 | 125  | -125 | JKL4323
2018-10-03 14:41:00 | 126  | -126 | JKL4324
2018-10-03 14:51:00 | 127  | -127 | JKL4325
2018-10-04 14:11:00 | 123  | -123 | JKL4321
2018-10-04 14:21:00 | 124  | -124 | JKL4322
2018-10-04 14:31:00 | 125  | -125 | JKL4323
2018-10-04 14:41:00 | 126  | -126 | JKL4324
2018-10-04 14:51:00 | 127  | -127 | JKL4325
```

My query:

```
SELECT
    MAX(gpsDateTime) AS Timee,
    long, lat, fleetNumber 
FROM
    GPS 
WHERE
    CAST(gpsDateTime AS DATE) =  '2018-10-03' 
GROUP BY
    fleetNumber, gpsDateTime, long, lat 
ORDER BY
    Timee DESC
```

but result is returned like this:

```
2018-10-03 14:11:00 |123 |-123|ABC1234
2018-10-03 14:21:00 |124 |-124|ABC1234
2018-10-03 14:31:00 |125 |-125|ABC1234
2018-10-03 14:41:00 |126 |-126|ABC1234
2018-10-03 14:51:00 |127 |-127|ABC1234

2018-10-03 14:11:00 |123 |-123|JKL4321
2018-10-03 14:21:00 |124 |-124|JKL4322
2018-10-03 14:31:00 |125 |-125|JKL4323
2018-10-03 14:41:00 |126 |-126|JKL4324
2018-10-03 14:51:00 |127 |-127|JKL4325
```

I need the result like this (only the latest one each fleetNumber):

```
2018-10-03 14:51:00 |127 |-127|ABC1234
2018-10-03 14:51:00 |127 |-127|JKL4325
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use row_number()

```
select * from
(
select gpsDateTime as Timee,long,lat, fleetNumber,row_number() over(partition by fleetNumber order by gpsDateTime desc ) as rn
from GPS 
Where cast(gpsDateTime as Date) =  '2018-10-03' 
)X where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using windows function as the fellow answer is a better option also You can achieve your requirement via derived table which is independent of SQL Server,

```
  select B.Timee,A.long,A.lat, A.fleetNumber 
  from GPS A inner join
  (select max(gpsDateTime) as Timee,fleetNumber 
  from GPS 
  Where cast(gpsDateTime as Date) =  '2018-10-03' 
  group by fleetNumber,gpsDateTime) B
  on A.gpsDateTime=B.Timee and A.fleetNumber= B.fleetNumber
```